# How to index this couchbase query

Tags: couchbase, sql++

**I am try to index this query but I don't how to do so**

```
const query = `SELECT r.*, r.itemName as name, r.createdBy.timestamp AS modifiedOn
               FROM report r
               LET groupReportIds = (SELECT rg.reportGuid
                      FROM report rg
                      WHERE rg.eventType = 'GROUP_SHARING' AND LOWER(rg.userEmail) = LOWER("${email}"))
               WHERE (ANY u in groupReportIds SATISFIES u.reportGuid = r.details.guid  END)`;
```

Comment: What version of Couchbase are you using? Have you tried the index advisor? https://index-advisor.couchbase.com/indexadvisor/#1 (or it's built in if you are using the enterprise edition)

Comment: @MatthewGroves I am using the enterprise edition

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE INDEX ix1 ON report(LOWER(userEmail), reportGuid) WHERE eventType = "GROUP_SHARING";
CREATE INDEX ix2 ON report(details.guid);

WITH groupReportIds AS (SELECT RAW rg.reportGuid
                        FROM report rg
                        WHERE rg.eventType = "GROUP_SHARING"
                            AND LOWER(rg.userEmail) = LOWER("${email}"))
SELECT r.*, r.itemName as name, r.createdBy.timestamp AS modifiedOn
FROM report r
WHERE r.details.guid IN groupReportIds;
```

Comment: But I think it's the groupReportIds array slowing down the query. It's possible to index this particular line. (ANY u in groupReportIds SATISFIES u.reportGuid = r.details.guid  END)`;

Comment: I am getting this error when I run this query:
{
    "code": 3000,
    "msg": "syntax error - at WITH",
    "query_from_user": "WITH groupReportIds AS (SELECT RAW rg.reportGuid\n                        FROM report rg\n                        WHERE rg.eventType = \"GROUP_SHARING\"\n                            AND LOWER(rg.userEmail) = LOWER(\"babatunde.o.abolaji@pwc.com\"))\nSELECT r.*, r.itemName as name, r.createdBy.timestamp AS modifiedOn\nFROM report r\nWHERE r.details.guid IN groupReportIds;"
  }